# Conditionally update record based on join values

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am wondering if SQL can accomplish this by itself or if I should use PHP.

The (golf) database has a `rounds` table and a `holes` table.  `rounds.id` is stored in the hole records for the round.

`holes` table has (among many other fields) `firstPutt`, `secondPutt`, `thirdPutt`.  These are floats storing distances and defaulting to zero.

What my employer would like to do is to store in the rounds table the sum for a round of the length of the last putt made for all holes in that round.

I realize that if I had a `putts` table referencing `holes.id` this would be a better structure but that is not possible at present.

So the update in pseudoSQL would be something like

```
UPDATE holes h, rounds r
SET r.sumOfLastPutts = (
SELECT thirdPutt if thirdPutt is not 0 
  OR secondPutt if secondPutt is not zero AND thirdPutt is zero 
  OR firstPutt if firstPutt is not zero AND secondPutt is zero)
) WHERE h.round = rounds.id
```

Is that possible using just SQL?

In this example the number for the round would be 145, the sum of the numbers in the red boxes.

[image: data]

Going off Martin Parkin's answer I can get a single round's sum like this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN h.thirdPutt != 0 THEN h.thirdPutt
    WHEN h.secondPutt != 0 THEN h.secondPutt
    WHEN h.firstPutt != 0 THEN h.firstPutt
  END
)
FROM holes h
WHERE h.round = 3044
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, which seems to offer what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE rounds r, holes h
  SET r.sumOfLastPutts =
    CASE
      WHEN h.thirdPutt != 0 THEN h.thirdPutt
      WHEN h.secondPutt != 0 THEN h.secondPutt
      WHEN h.firstPutt != 0 THEN h.firstPutt
    END
  WHERE h.round = r.id;
```

There's a SQLFiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f501c/1).

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I'm excited to learn about CASE in SQL.  I was not aware.  Your answer is close but it does not sum the multiple rows of `holes` records where h.round = r.id.  I added an pictorial example of some data to my question.  In the example your query gets a value of 12 but the sum is 145.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
UPDATE rounds r
  SET r.totalPuttDistance = (
    SELECT 
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN h.thirdPutt != 0 THEN h.thirdPutt
          WHEN h.secondPutt != 0 THEN h.secondPutt
          WHEN h.firstPutt != 0 THEN h.firstPutt
        END
       )
    FROM holes h
    WHERE h.round = r.id
)
```